# Searching for duplicates with Big-O time constraints

Tags: java, arrays, time, arraylist, big-o

For an assignment, I am to create a constructor taking a String[] **names** and int[] **rank** as parameters that accomplishes the following tasks in O(n log n):

(Data Validation):

1. Checks that **names** and **rank** are the same length --- (Time: **O(1)**)
2. Checks that both **names** and **rank** are not null --- (Time: **O(1)**)
3. Checks that **names** does not contain any duplicate or null strings --- (Time: **O(n^2)**) ???
4. Checks that **rank** contains only distinct elements --- (Time: ???)

(Actual Object declarance):

- Adds each index value of **names** and **rank** to an ArrayList of custom type(Time: **O(n)**)

For the project I am not allowed to use any data structure beyond arrays and ArrayLists (no Map or Set interfaces), but I may use the methods in the Arrays class to search and sort arrays. I don't see how to accomplish all of these things in O(n log n) time. I especially don't know how to do step 3 in less than O(n^2) time. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steps 1 & 2 are trivial.

Step 3:

- sort the array with `Arrays.sort(array)` => `O(n log n)`
- iterate over the array checking each entry vs. the next one (to see if you find a duplicate) => `O(n)`

==> Total = `O (n log n)`

Step 4: same methodology

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Having a sorted array would mean I would only need to compare names[i] with names[i+1], names[i+1] with names[i+2], and so on. Didn't think about this before.